# Android: Issue during Arraylist declaration

Tags: java, android, arraylist, declaration

If I declare Arraylist like this-

```
private ArrayList<Integer[]> nodeList;
```

then, while adding array into it, getting NullPointerException

But, if I change it to-

```
private ArrayList<Integer[]> nodeList= new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

-it works fine.

Why the first one fails!

Comment: As you state, in first case you declare it only, but its initial value is null.

Comment: @Avisek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065763/error-while-assigning-value-to-member-variable-after-declaring-the-object-null :) no offense but you should read some books about programming in java

Comment: ya am a noob & am clarifying while trying exercises. Actually, its much confusive to switch to JAVA from PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first only declares a variable, but does not create the actual object. only when you use `new`, you actually create the object.

In java unlike C++, declaring a variable does not allocate a [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) of it. To actually create the object, you need to explicitly create it [in your example: by using the `new` keyword].

(*)Note that this is only true to [reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#9317) types objects, and java [primitives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) are created with declaration.